# how to avoid this union select

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm cleaing up some old sql statements and there is a recurring pattern, statements like this:

```
select
  *
from
  tab_a a
where
  a.type in (  select 
                 column1 
               from 
                 view_b 
             union all 
               select 
                 column2 
               from 
                 view_b
            )
;
```

The problem is: view_b takes a lot of time/cpu and I'd love to reduce the SQL statements to calling the view only once. I don't want to touch view_b, it scares me. I only want to half the execution time by only calling it once.

Any good advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do an `unpivot`

```
create table view_b (
  col1 number,
  col2 number
);

insert into view_b values( 1, 2 );
insert into view_b values( 3, 4 );

select *
  from view_b
 unpivot( 
   val 
   for col in (col1 as '1', col2 as '2' ) );
```

So you could do something like

```
with unpivot_b as (
    select *
      from view_b
     unpivot( 
       val 
       for col in (col1 as '1', col2 as '2' ) )
)
select *
  from tab_a a
 where a.type in (select val
                    from unpivot_b);
```

Comment: this looks promising. I'll need some time to test it before I accept it.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not *scared* of an undocumented hint, you may use `MATERIALIZE` hint.

The advantage IMO is that you instructs the optimizer to do exact what is required:

- evaluate the view only once
- create the internal object from the result
- use it twice in the IN list

The query

```
with vb as (
  select /*+ MATERIALIZE */ column1, column2  from view_b 
)
select * from tab_a a
where type in (select column1 from vb
               union all
               select column2 from vb);
```

**Alternatively** you may used the *materialize inline views with ROWNUM* trick of [Tom Kite](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:587908400346860711)

This query evaluates the view only once and leads to the identical plan as while using the `MATERIALIZE` hint:

```
with vb as (
  select rownum rn,  /* rownum is used to materialize the view */
         column1, column2  from view_b 
)
select * from tab_a a
where type in (select column1 from vb
               union all
               select column2 from vb);
```

Comment: very interesting. I'm worried though that my colleagues will not like any tricks that are undocumented or hardly known. But it's a pretty cool solution.

Comment: @EasterBunnyBugSmasher in this case use the `pivot` approach from the other answer. This seems to be the second surest way.

Answer (score 1):

You could also switch to an `exists`... not sure if it would improve performance in your case or not.

```
select
  *
from
  tab_a a
where
  exists (  select
              1
            from 
              view_b 
            where 
              a.type in (column1, column2)
          )
;
```

Comment: This is interessting approach, but some care in test should be taken if the subquery can be *unnested*. If no the view will be evaluated *once for each row* from table `tab_a` (*twice for each row* from `tab_a` in the query from @GordonLinoff)

Answer (score 1):

Use two different conditions.  I would recommend `exists`:

```
select a.*
from tab_a a
where exists (select 1 from view_b b where b.column1 = a.type) or
      exists (select 1 from view_b b where b.column2 = a.type) ;
```

This should give the optimizer much more flexibility in optimizing the query.  Of course, performance depends on what the view is.  But for simple tables this can directly take advantage of indexes and with the right indexes would be very fast.